# Importing many successors relationships from Excel file to MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have prepared an excel file with data that I want to import into MS Project.

This should be done via the standard *Create new Project from Excel workbook* function where you map the column headers from the Excel file to the standard MS Project fields.

The Excel file contains primarily text that gets matched to the *Text1*, *Text2*, *Text3*, etc. standard fields in MS Project. Importing these fields works without problems.

One of the columns in the Excel file contains semicolon seperated values in order to establish predecessor-successor relationships between tasks from the get-go.

The values in the successor column are formatted as required by MS Project (seperated by semicolons, cell data type is Text). E.g.:

```
45;46;48;52;64;102;143;160;(...)
```

This particular column presents a problem to MS Project when importing. The mapping matrix does not recognize the excel columns anymore:

[image]

When I delete this column from the excel file, all column headers appear as normal.

There are a couple of additional details that I'd like to mention:

- The successor column contains cells with a large number of successor references (currently the longest entry contains 954 characters in total).
- I've tested the import of successors successfully in a smaller context (less successor values).
- I'm using MS Project 2013
- The Excel worksheet does not contain spaces or other special characters in its name - as outlined here:

[How to Import Excel Worksheet into Microsoft Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264189/how-to-import-excel-worksheet-into-microsoft-project)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/f4fe3b71-462a-4ee8-a941-ab84e63476fb/cant-import-excel-file-into-msproject-2013?forum=projectonline

Does anybody have an idea as to why this bug is appearing?

Or does the problem lie with the big scope?

Comment: Try reducing the longest successor lists to be no more than 900 characters. Years ago I found a similar limit to be a little over 900... You may have to manually recreate a few links, but you'll get most of it in automatically. And if not 900, try 800, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I still could not solve the problem when importing from an Excel worksheet. 
However, I've found a workaround by simply using a CSV file for the import instead.

**The mapping matrix appears as usual and all successors are also imported correctly.**

So, if you're having the same problem - save your Excel file as a CSV file and re-try the import from MS Project.